# Add prefix (a or an) to a word using php

Tags: php

How to add dynamic prefix a or an to a word using php according to first letter as per english language?

Example

1. elephant should be an elephant
2. lion should be a lion and so on

This question is about put a php logic in code where if we have dynamic word say $word, we need to get Articles(as per English grammar ) as prefix to a word.
Eg. I have dynamic sentence like :

This is $prefix(need article) $word/Dynamic word/

Now I need to manipulate $prefix as per dynamic word - $word. Please suggest any relevant answer or temporary fix to this problem as its very difficult to put an article before word as per  English Grammar rules.

Comment: Check if the 1st character of your string is a vowel then add 'an', otherwise add 'a'. Simple.

Comment: no vowel alone cant decide a or an university starts with a vowel but sounds like 'Yew' so its a university. Honest does not start with vowel but sounds like 'Onest' so its an honest and so on..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply impliment following code

```
$word = "elephant"; // put word for which you want prefix
$vowelArry = array('a','e','i','o','u');  // array of vowel
$prefix = in_array(strtolower(substr($word ,0,1)),$vowelArry)? "an" : "a"; // logic to add prefix
$updated_word = $prefix." ".$word // updated word
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: how about university, honest ? it will be 'a university' , 'an honest'

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty you are correct. There is some exception cases where this will not work.

Comment: 'h' in front of a vowel is an exception, yes.

Comment: No No No that's not an exception, that's language! If we cannot come up with a logic for that we cannot disregard those cases as exceptions. That's proper English grammar with reasoning, not an exceptional case.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky We are talking in terms of logic of a code. These are some case where this logic has limitation hence it's considered as exceptions. (specially where English word has silent characters)

Answer (score 1):

This answer is building off of Fluffeh, but using a function:

```
function proper($str) {
    $vowels = array('a','e','i','o','u');
    if(in_array(strtolower($str[0]), $vowels)) $prefix = "an "; else $prefix = "a ";
    $str = $prefix.$str;
    return $str;
}

echo proper($str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply check the first letter of each word by treating it as an array like this:

```
<?php

    $yourWord="example";
    if(in_array(strtolower($yourWord[0]),array('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')))
    {
        $prefix=" an ";
    }
    else
    {
        $prefix=" a ";
    }

    echo $prefix.$yourWord

?>
```

The catch is that in correct English, some words that don't start with a vowel actually sound like they so - and so should use the prefix as such.

Example: *An* honorary...

Comment: And "an university"? Where is a function that works?